# AWS ALB vs Docker swarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm, aws-alb

I have an application running on AWS EC2. In order to get high availability, we are planning to set up AWS Load balancer and host the application in a minimum of 2 EC2 instances.

We also heard about Docker swarm, in which we can create a service with 2 managers on 2 separate EC2 instances and the swarm will take care of the rest (instead of using ALB with 2 EC2). It will balance the load to all the containers inside the cluster and it also restarts the container if anything makes this go down.

So I want to know which is the best choice for my case. The application won't get heavy load/traffic. Why I choose load balancer is for high availability. If 1 instance goes down the other will be taken care of this.

If there are any other choices to fulfill my requirements, it will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume it's a stateless application.

A combination of both Swarm & ALB is what you can go for but you will need to incorporate autoscaling etc sooner or later which means you will need to manage the swarm cluster & maintain it. 
With ALB you will get real good metrics which you will surely miss while using Swarm.

BUT, you do have a few better options which will manage the cluster for you. You just will have to manage & maintain the docker images -

1. Use ECS.
2. Use EKS (only in `us-east-1` as if now)
3. Use ElasticBeanstalk MultiContainer.

Ref -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html
https://aws.amazon.com/eks/

Comment: By docker's routing mesh functionality, it will take care of the load balancing, right?  I'm thinking about avoiding ALB if we are using Docker swarm.

Comment: Yes, it will but how will you manage at DNS level. What if instance get's crashed at kernel level etc. With ALB you can monitor health & also helps you manage DNS without many changes. I would suggest ALB at least in prod. Also, there are many configurations which you can set at ALB but might not in docker swarm VIP load balancing.